# OpenLDAP associate existing users to an organization unit (OU)

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldif

I created an OpenLDAP server on Ubuntu 22.04, and created users but forgot to add them to a organizational unit (ou). How can I associate them all to an ou now ?
The actual server looks like this:

```
dn=company
    ou=Users
    uid=user1
    uid=user2
    uid=user3
    ...
```

What I would like is:

```
dn=company
    ou=Users
        uid=user1
        uid=user2
        uid=user3
        ...
```

Concretely, I would like to go from this:

```
uid=user1,dc=example,dc=fr
```

to this:

```
uid=user1,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=fr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an `ou` attribute to the entry is one thing, moving the entry in the DIT is another thing. For the latter, you need to use the [`newsuperior`](https://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch8/#newsuperior)  directive.

- Using `ldapmodify -f` with `changetype: (modrdn|moddn)` :

  ```
  dn: uid=user1,dc=example,dc=fr
  changetype: modrdn
  # rdn unchanged
  newrdn: uid=user1
  # deletes old entry
  deleteoldrdn: 1
  # adds to Users hierarchy
  newsuperior: ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
  ```
- Using `ldapmodrdn -r -s <newsuperior> <dn> <newrdn>` :

  ```
  ldapmodrdn -r -s "ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com" "uid=user1,dc=example,dc=fr" "uid=user1"
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I just found an answer on my own.
I simply did a LDIF file `modify.ldif`:

```
dn: uid=user1,dc=example,dc=fr
changetype: modify
add: ou
ou: Users
```

And then `ldapmodify -x -D cn=admin,dc=example,dc=fr -W -f ./modify.ldif`

Comment: Note that this adds an attribute `ou: Users` to the entry but does not modify the DIT, ie. it doesn't move it from `uid=user1,dc=example,dc=fr` to `uid=user1,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=fr`, so you will be able to use a search filter `ou=Users`, but you won't have the benefit of having a specific base for users. See my answer below.